VSCode on wsl2 cant find gcc/g++
I try to run a .c with vscode on a wsl environment. I have both gcc and g++ installed. I verified that on a vscode terminal as explained in the guide. Í also have all the necessary extensions installed.
My problem: Step 3, choosing a compiler for the project fails - vscode can't find the compiler. How do I configure vscode to use my compiler?
Bellow is a screenshot of the vscode. No errors appear. The menu only contain one option, nothing about gcc as in the guide.


Show any errors you get, the screenshots of how you've verified that you have GCC installed, and so on.

@HolyBlackCat I added a screenshot. There are no errors.

Ok. What exactly is "step 3" that you're referring to? What section of that tutorial?

@HolyBlackCat It refers to the Run helloworld.cpp section. The link is fixed now.

You're pressing "Run", not "Debug", right?

@HolyBlackCat Currently there is no difference, both options yield no reaction of any kind from vscode.

I just did a clean installation of Ubuntu 24.04 in a VM, and I do see all the options shown in the tutorial.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Edit: I've now also ran into the same behavior where gdb was not installed. Check that it is (see if which gdb returns a path), and install it if not (sudo apt install gdb). If vscode still doesn't work in run or debug, try my suggestions below.
I ran into this same issue in WSL2. I tried a few different solutions form Can't compile code "launch: program <program_path> does not exist ", but these are for windows, not WSL. However, that made me look into what the correct .vscode files are needed to launch successfully.
Overall, I think the issue is vscode isn't looking in the right spot to find your compiler, but providing a launch.json file with the correct path to gcc/g++ seems to show it where to look. After doing so, when I create a new C++ project in vscode on WSL2, gcc and g++ show up even when I don't supply a launch.json or tasks.json file, and the default tasks.json created by the C/C++ extension works as expected. I was then able to complete the tutorial here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux, which is also where I found the following launch.json file that worked for my WSL2 installation (as g++ is installed by default under /usr/bin/g++). Note you might need to install gdb, which should install be default to /usr/bin/gdb.
Placing this file at .vscode/launch.json worked for me:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++: g++ build and debug active file",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
    }
  ]
}

Be sure to select g++ when launching or you'll get an error. If you select the wrong compiler, you can delete .vscode\task.json to select a new one, or edit the command path.
If this doesn't work for you, you could alternatively try looking at the settings in the c_cpp_properties.json (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference)
